# PLIST read/write with generic dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, file, generics, plist

I'm trying to add load/save functions to a generic caching class, like this:

```
class Cache<T:Hashable, U:AnyObject> {
    private var cache: [T:U] = [:]
    private var url: NSURL!
    func load() {
        if let path = self.url where NSFileManager().isReadableFileAtPath(path.path!) {
            if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: path) {
                // The next line is rejected by the compiler as always failing the cast
                cache = (dict as? DictType)!
            }
        }
    }

    func save() {
        if let path = self.url where NSFileManager().isWritableFileAtPath(path.path!) {
            // The next line is rejected by the compiler as the method not existing
            let result = cache.writeToURL(path, atomically: false)
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

If I use concrete types this works, but translating to generics apparently takes away enough information that the compiler is no longer willing to accept it. **Is there a way to do this?**

I also tried looping through the NSDictionary, but for example the loop in the load routine then complains it doesn't have a type for the key (and won't accept what's returned from allKeys); nor can I cast / coerce to the type T.

Comment: The question has less information to construct a valid solution. What is a ```DictType```?

Comment: Missed that in simplifying. It's just [T:U]